# Summarize a skills rating table with an unknown number of skill columns in Google Sheet using pure formulas and no GAS

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I am unable to share a working sheet.

I have a sheet with a table like so:

| Name | Skill 1 | Skill 2 | Skill 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | high | medium | low | none |
| two |  |  |  |  |
| three | low | medium | high | none |
| four | low | high | hig |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

- It has an unknown number of rows
- It has 3 skill columns today, but more skills may be added later
- Not all rows are filled out

I want to summarize the table like so:

| Skill | high | medium | low | none |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Skill 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Skill 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Skill 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Basically I am showing each skill and how many high/medium/low/none they have.

I am trying to use formulas so everything is dynamic. Meaning, if more names are added, or if more skills are added, then the table automatically shows it.

I can get a list of skills from the first table like so:

```
={
    "Area";
    TRANSPOSE(SORT(Ratings!B1:1))
}
```

But that is as far as I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(Ratings!B2:5000="",,Ratings!B1:1&"×"&Ratings!B2:5000)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'Skill'"))
```

[image]

Comment: @MattKing Why `ARRAYFORMULA`? `INDEX` seems to work too.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan because to the extent that Stack is supposed to be a reference for future users, rather than just a "help desk" for current users, INDEX() is more confusing.  If someone were to look up what INDEX() does, they would be confused about why it was used, and unaware that it's was used because nerds like us get excited by a solution that has fewer characters.

Comment: also, if @player0 had wanted to make it shorter, he could have just done it without the "IF()" mask up front.

=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Ratings!B1:1&"x"&Ratings!B2:5000),"x",0,0),"select Col1,Count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'Skill'")

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you!